Model Building - Unable to use output from one tool in the next tool?
I am new to QGIS and would like to set up a model to combine multiple steps into one.
The overview:
Inputs: Satellite Image, Masking area of interest (shapefile)
Tool 1: Clip raster by mask layer

Input the satellite image layer and clip it using the masking area of interest
Output: clipped_satellite_image

Tool 2: Raster pixels to polygons

Error here

I am unable to select the output from Tool 1 and use it to convert the clipped area from raster to pixels. I am only able to select one of the input variables. I attached a photo of my issue. Is there a way I can view the requirements of a tool's input argument?

If it is worth anything, the next step would be to warp (reproject), but only if the .tif file has a certain pattern in its name. Then each image will be exported to a .csv file. So my second question here is, is that workflow possible to achieve using only the model builder or does it still require manual intervention?

Have you made sure to switch from model input to algorithm output left of the dropdown menu?


thank you so much! i really appreciate it. vielen dank!
